# Generalization of the Riemann curvature tensor; does it exist?

Tags: differential

The Riemannian curvature tensor (also holding for manifolds with torsion) is for the vector fields $X,Y,Z$ formally given by:
$R(X,Y)Z = (\nabla_X \nabla_Y - \nabla_Y \nabla_X - \nabla_{[X,Y]})Z$.

This tensor clearly exist for smooth manifolds with connection. But what is if the manifold is non-smooth and one cannot find a connection because it is not defined everywhere on the manifold? Are there some generalizations of this curvature tensor (and also generalizations of the connection)?

Comment: Addendum: The curvature Tensor can be obtained by considering the [path-ordered exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) around a closed loop. When one has a non-continuous connection, one can integrate over the connection at first and then evaluate the exponential. Finally, the result can be compared with the value of the path-ordered exponential $1+R(X,Y)|X||Y|+...$ where $X,Y$ generate a parallelogram and with absolute values $|...|$